# Pandasでのデータ処理を高速化したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas

PandasのDataframeで、特定条件の数値を統一したいです。
例えばこのようなdfがあります。

```
    id  label
0   a     1
1   a     2
2   a     1
3   b     2
4   b     2
5   c     2
6   a     1
7   b     1
8   b     2
```

aとbは複数のラベルを持っているため、数の多いラベルをidのラベルにしたいです。
つまり、aのラベルを全て1に、bのラベルを全て2に統一したいです。
この作業に対して2つの案を考えました。

1.value_countsで集計してwhere, applyで置き換える

```
def change_label(old_l,new_l):
    return new_l

ids = new_df['id'].unique()
for i in trange(len(ids)):
    new_label = list(new_df[new_df['id']==ids[i]]['label'].value_counts().items())[0][0]
    new_df['label'].where(new_df['id'] != ids[i], 
                                 new_df['label'].apply(lambda x:change_label(x,new_label)), 
                                 inplace=True)
```

2.重複データは最終的に必要がないので、value_countsで集計したあとに辞書に入れる

```
ids = new_df['id'].unique()
new_dict = {}
for i in trange(len(ids)):
    if new_df[new_df['id']==ids[i]]['label'].nunique()>1:
        new_label = list(new_df[new_df['id']==ids[i]]['label'].value_counts().items())[0][0]
        new_dict.update({ids[i]:new_label})
    else:
        new_dict.update({ids[i]:new_df[new_df['id']==ids[i]]['label'].unique()[0]})
```

案2は案1より高速化できたが、実際大量なデータを扱うため、さらに高速化したいです。
他に知見がありましたら、ご教示願いたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とりあえず、２番目の方法と同様の dict型のデータ(`new_dict`)を作成する方法ですが、
**pandas** には最頻値を求める `Series.mode()` という関数がありますので、２番目のコードを

```
new_dict = {}
for id in new_df['id'].unique():
    new_label =  new_df[new_df['id']==id]['label'].mode()[0]
    new_dict.update({id: new_label})
```

と書き直すことができます。（これで最初のコードに比べ数倍速くなります）
更には ループ処理を、`GroupBy.apply()`にて書き換えることが出来ますので、

```
new_dict = new_df.groupby('id')['label'].apply(lambda d: d.mode()[0])
```

と書き直すことができ、速度も10倍近く速くなります。

> この結果のデータはSeries型となっております。もしdict型のデータを得たい場合 `new_dict.to_dict()` としてください

あとはこれを `Series.map()` を使うことでもとのDataFrameに適用できますので

```
dic = new_df.groupby('id')['label'].apply(lambda d: d.mode()[0])
new_df['label'] = new_df['id'].map(dict)
```

で良いかと思います。

ついでに書きますと、上記のコードはさらに `GroupBy.transform()` を使って

```
new_df['label'] = new_df.groupby('id')['label'].transform(lambda s:s.mode()[0])
```

と１行でまとめることができます（速度的にはあまりメリットはありませんが）

---

一応、動作サンプルです。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import trange
import timeit

### 元のコード（２番）
def org_fnc(new_df):
    ids = new_df['id'].unique()
    new_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(ids)):
        if new_df[new_df['id']==ids[i]]['label'].nunique()>1:
            new_label = list(new_df[new_df['id']==ids[i]]['label'].value_counts().items())[0][0]
            new_dict.update({ids[i]:new_label})
        else:
            new_dict.update({ids[i]:new_df[new_df['id']==ids[i]]['label'].unique()[0]})
    return new_dict

### 修正コード
def new_fnc(new_df):
    new_dict =  new_df.groupby('id')['label'].apply(lambda d: d.mode()[0]).to_dict()
    return new_dict

N = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.random.choice(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'], N),
    'label': np.random.randint(1,20,N)
})

### 結果を比較
print(org_fnc(df.copy()))
#{'e': 16, 'a': 17, 'f': 14, 'b': 6, 'c': 3, 'g': 2, 'd': 13}
print(new_fnc(df.copy()))
#{'e': 16, 'a': 17, 'f': 14, 'b': 6, 'c': 3, 'g': 2, 'd': 13}

### 時間を確認
print(timeit.timeit(lambda:org_fnc(df.copy()), number=100))
#14.239833151672423
print(timeit.timeit(lambda:new_fnc(df.copy()), number=100))
#0.9063719363020688
```

Answer (score 0):

df.loc[df["id"] == "a", "label"] = 1